# div with position absolute but still taking up space on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, absolute

i wanna make an asset that shows up on scroll top it's on the left and when user scrolls down it comes up from right supposed as if from none to the left here the problem:

it's position is absolute but it still taking up space on the page it means when you scoll to the right, out of the page actual website you find an empty area and that's the problem here my code any suggestions please...

```js
function secondAssets() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 600 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 600){
        document.querySelector('.asset1-2').style = 'margin-left: 0px;'
        document.querySelector('.asset2-2').style = 'right: -120px;'
        document.querySelector('.asset1-2 span').style = 'left: 17px;'
    }else {
    document.querySelector('.asset1-2').style = 'margin-left: 1500px;'
    document.querySelector('.asset2-2').style = 'right: -1800px;'
    document.querySelector('.asset1-2 span').style = 'left: 1500px;'
    }
}
```

```css
.second-assets {
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.second-assets ul {
    display: flex;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.second-assets .asset1-2 {
    width: 1100px;
}


.second-assets .asset2-2 {
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -120px;
}

.second-assets .asset1-2 img {
    width: 1100px;
    height: 80px;
}

.second-assets .asset2-2 img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px;
}

.second-assets .asset1-2 {
    margin-left: 1500px;
    transition: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0.79) 1s;
}

.second-assets .asset2-2 {
    right: -1800px;
    transition: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0.79) 1s;
}

.second-assets .asset1-2 span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 17px;
    transition: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0.79) 1s;
    left: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page3">
        <div class="second-assets">
            <ul>                             <!--images urls first: https://imgur.com/UFPkTIr
                                               second: https://imgur.com/6xWwIQu -->
                <li class="asset1-2"><img src="images/illustrator_pics/Asset%2011@4x.png" alt=""><span>Imobile Shop HTML CSS JavaScript</span></li>
                <li class="asset2-2"><img src="images/illustrator_pics/Asset%2012@4x.png" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        
</div>
```

Comment: Try to set the overflow of the parent div to hidden like. `.page3{ overflow:hidden; position:relative; }`

Comment: i've tried to do position relative for page3 and doesn't get fixed but that's right it's fixed with the overflow thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it helped!